# ModuleNotFoundError when using Python Schedule

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a python program using a raspberry pi to automatically turn on my Christmas lights. I got this to work using a While True loop and if statements, but to make it better I want to implement the Schedule library. Whenever I try to run my program I always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/schedule_test.py",line 1, in <module>
  import schedule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'
```

I ran the pip install schedule at least 3 times to make sure it was installed.

Here is the rest of the code to my program

```
import schedule
import requests
import json
import time

from pylibftdi import BitBangDevice
relay1 = BitBandDevice(device_id='AR0K0V9A')

webhook_url = 'url' #My URL works, I just took it out here

def notify(data):
 print('Notifing')
 r = requests.post(webhoor_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

def off():
 relay1.port = 0
 data = {'value1':'turned off'}
 notify(data)

def on():
 relay1.port = 255
 data = {'value1':'turned on'}
 notify(data)

schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(on)
schedule.every().day.at("22:00").do(off)

while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)
```

I looked up when other people showed how to use schedule and copy/pasted their code and I still got the same error

Comment: If you run `pip show schedule` can you see the module? Maybe check if you installed it under the right python version.

Comment: How you install this module? If you think you did well then try to run `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze` and see listed module.

Comment: Maybe you installed `schedule` for the wrong python version. If you use Python 3 (which you should), then do a `python3 -m pip install schedule`.

Comment: @CoderCharmander That worked, thank you!